# Split a string in array elements into an array using explode() or preg_split()

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I have an array with each element is a string like this:

```
$items[0] = "*1*x *2858* in *1* with selected image to print at *http://mysite.com/test.jpg*"
```

and

```
$items[1] = "*2*x *2353* in *2* with selected image to print at *http://mysite.com/test1.jpg*"
```

How can I split this array elements into a 2nd dimension array so that it becomes:

```
$items[0][quantity] == 1
$items[0][product_id] == 2858
$items[0][variation} == 1
$items[0][selectedImageUrl] == "http://mysite.com/test.jpg"
```

and

```
$items[1][quantity] == 2
$items[1][product_id] == 2353
$items[1][variation} == 2
$items[1][selectedImageUrl] == "http://mysite.com/test1.jpg"
```

Thanks so much for your help!

---

@Cal

This is what I have when applying your code.

I applied it to my situation and this is what I have:

```
function parse_my_str($str){
  $bits = explode(' ', $str);
  $out['selectedImageUrl'] = array_pop($bits);
  $out['product_id'] = $bits[1];
  $out['variation'] = $bits[3];
  $bits = explode('*', $str);
  $out['quantity'] = $bits[1];
  return $out;
}

$items = explode("||", $_SESSION['mp_shipping_info']['special_instructions']); 
foreach ($items as $i => $v) {
    $items[$i] = parse_my_str($v);
    print_r($items[$i]);
}
```

But i've got

```
Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => *http://youparkrudely.com/files/2012/04/2011-Aston-Martin-Rapide-026.jpg* [product_id] => *2858* [variation] => *1* [quantity] => 1 ) Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => [product_id] => [variation] => [quantity] => )
```

---

@Cal

```
    Array ( 
[selectedImageUrl] => *http://youparkrudely.com/files/2012/04/2011-Aston-Martin-Rapide-026.jpg* 
[product_id] => *2858* 
[variation] => *1* 
[quantity] => 1 ) 
Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => [product_id] => [variation] => [quantity] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for new string, using `preg_match()` instead:

```
$str = "*1*x *2858* in *1* with selected image to print at *http://mysite.com/test.jpg*";
$arr = parse_my_str($str);
print_r($arr);

function parse_my_str($str){
  preg_match_all('!\\*(.*?)\\*!', $str, $m);
  return array(
    'quantity' => $m[1][0],
    'product_id' => $m[1][1],
    'variation' => $m[1][2],
    'selectedImageUrl' => $m[1][3],
  );
}
```

For your example, you'd use the function like this:

```
foreach ($items as $k => $v) $items[$k] = parse_my_str($v);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Cal. I posted my result above, could you please take a look?

Comment: have you see it now? it's below my original question. we are almost there, thanks so much!

Comment: what you've got is correct! delete `print_r($items[$i])` and put `print_r($items)` at the end

Comment: I've got print_r($items[$i]) just to see the outcome. the problem is it has the star (*) in front and at the end of each second dimension array elements.

Comment: like this 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => *http://youparkrudely.com/files/2012/04/2011-Aston-Martin-Rapide-026.jpg* [product_id] => *2858* [variation] => *1* [quantity] => 1 ) [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => *http://youparkrudely.com/files/2012/04/2011-Aston-Martin-Rapide-026.jpg* [product_id] => *2858* [variation] => *1* [quantity] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [selectedImageUrl] => [product_id] => [variation] => [quantity] => ) )

Comment: formattingggg.... sorry, it's like this: [selectedImageUrl] => *http://youparkrudely.com/files/2012/something.jpg* and [product_id] => *2858* [variation] => *1*; quantity is ok though.

Comment: i just format it properly in my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: also, how can i trim / get rid of the last empty element in array $items?

Comment: Thanks so much. That's work. How can we get rid of the * though, it still showing as above.

Comment: im sorry, did notice you updated the post. i tested it, and IT WORKS PERFECTLY!!! Thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: i'd love to vote up, but i don't have enough reputation. thanks again man!

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a `preg_match()` solution and a regular expression.  Not sure if I matched things exactly but here is a simple example.

```
// Regular Expression
$pattern = '/^\*(\d+)\*x (\d+) in (\d+) with selected image to print at (.+)$/';
preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches );
```

if you `var_dump()` `$matches` you'll get this:

```
array(5) {
[0]=> string(74) "*2*x 2353 in 2 with selected image to print at http://mysite.com/test1.jpg" 
[1]=> string(1) "2" 
[2]=> string(4) "2353" 
[3]=> string(1) "2" 
[4]=> string(27) "http://mysite.com/test1.jpg" 
}
```

You would have to loop through your array of items.

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) :

    preg_match( $pattern, $value, $matches );

    $items[$key]['quantity'] = $matches[1];
    $items[$key]['product_id'] = $matches[2];
    $items[$key]['variation'] = $matches[3];
    $items[$key]['selectedImageURL'] = $matches[4];

endforeach;
```

I would also suggest a custom function.

If you need some help on regular expression I suggest starting here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$items[0] = "*1*x 2858 in 1 with selected image to print at http://mysite.com/test.jpg";
$items[1] = "*2*x 2353 in 2 with selected image to print at http://mysite.com/test1.jpg";

foreach ($items as $key=>$item){
    $temp = explode(" ", $item);
    $items[$key] = array();
    $items[$key]['quantity'] = $temp[0];
    $items[$key]['product_id'] = $temp[1];
    $items[$key]['variation'] = $temp[3];
    $items[$key]['selectedImageURL'] = $temp[10];
}

print_r($items);
```

Something along those lines should work. Assuming, of course, that your quantity and variation remain the same.

Comment: `explode()` takes 2 arguments and this code does not do what the question is asking.

Comment: yes, I realize - I clicked post before I was done, my mistake

Comment: Almost there - here's a version of your code that will *almost* work, but the quantity is still wrong: http://codepad.org/8ERL5mSW

Comment: Yeah, I actually got around to testing...oh well, thanks for your help :)

Comment: i know. that's some real cool code! but thank you for trying. i do appreciate that.